# Use optional chaning to increment object property

Tags: javascript, operators, optional-chaining

I want to increment an object value using the optional chaning operator (?.).
In my example I want to increase the age of a Person by one in a function called birthday() only if an age is set for the current person.
The line with the if clause works fine (also tenary if works obviously). However I wanted to know if something like the line below is possible. The syntax given results in an SyntaxError: invalid increment/decrement operand. Maybe its an issue based on the operator precedence, but I have now clue how to solve it.

```js
class Person {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
}
let peter = new Person("Peter", 27);
let paul = new Person("Paul", undefined);

Person.prototype.birthday = function() {
  if (this.age) this.age++;
};

//Person.prototype.birthday = function(){this?.age++};

peter.birthday();
paul.birthday();
console.log(peter, paul);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to increment an object value using the optional chaning operator (?.)

You can't. The reason is that the result of optional chaining is just a value, not a property reference, so you can't use any of the operators that write back to the property (like `++`, `--`, `+=`, etc.). (That's shown by [this part](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-optional-chaining-evaluation) of the specification.) In contrast, the result of a [property acccessor](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-optional-chaining-evaluation) like `this.age` is (in specification terms) a reference to the property, so the operator can write back to the property.

Your version with `if` is the way to handle this.

---

But separately, just as a side note, your two statements **do different things**.

Your optional chaining (`this?.age`) is checking that `this` is not nullish. But your `if` is checking that `this.age` is not nullish. The equivalent `if` would be `if (this) { this.age++; }`. But from the overall code context, you don't want that, you want what you currently have in the `if`, though I think I'd probably make it a more specific check:

```
if (this.age !== undefined) {
    this.age++;
}
```

I say that because `0` is falsy, so just `if (this.age)` would not increment `0`.